# Unauthorized error when build docker image with jib, using a custom base image

Tags: spring, docker, maven, docker-toolbox, jib

I've to create a docker image, starting from a distroless base image, with some custom files. I use JIB with maven on my spring boot project.
I'm working on Windows 7 with Docker toolbox.
this is the step than I do for now:

1) create **Dockerfile** with these entries:

```
FROM gcr.io/distroless/java:8
COPY known_hosts  ~/.ssh/known_hosts
EXPOSE 8888
```

2) execute the command:

```
docker build -t conf_server_image .
```

3) added follow lines on pom.xml:

```
          <plugin>
              <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
              <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.1.0</version>
              <configuration>
                <from>
                    <image>conf_server_image:latest</image>
                </from>
                <to>
                  <image>${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</image>
                </to>
                <container>
                    <jvmFlags>
                        <jvmFlag>-Xms512m</jvmFlag>
                        <jvmFlag>-Xmx512m</jvmFlag>
                    </jvmFlags>
                </container>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

4) execute command (with my ID ad pwd of docker.io):

```
docker login
```

4) execute the build command

```
mvnw clean compile jib:dockerBuild
```

but the process return me this error:

```
[INFO] Executing tasks:
[INFO] [============                  ] 40,0% complete
[INFO] > building image to Docker daemon
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.941 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-10T11:26:59+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:2.1.0:dockerBuild (default-cli) on project sirio-configuration-server: Build to Docker daemon failed, pe
haps you should make sure your credentials for 'registry-1.docker.io/library/conf_server_image' are set up correctly. See https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/mast
r/docs/faq.md#what-should-i-do-when-the-registry-responds-with-unauthorized for help: Unauthorized for registry-1.docker.io/library/conf_server_image: 401 Unauthorized
[ERROR] {"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"repository","Class":"","Name":"library/conf_server_image","Action":"pull"}]}]}
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

what am i forgetting?
Thanks

Comment: After hours of struggle I found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76695342/5465632) and have added here.

Answer (score 2):

File `settings.xml` inside `.m2` folder should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
      <server>
        <id>registry-1.docker.io</id>
        <username>YOUR_DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME</username>
        <password>YOUR_DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD</password>
      </server>
    </servers>
 </settings>
```

Reference: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Answer (score 1):

`conf_server_image:latest` as an image reference points to Docker Hub (alias for `library/conf_server_image:latest`). For example, in `Dockerfile`, when you say

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
```

Docker CLI downloads the `openjdk` image on Docker Hub.

```
$ docker pull openjdk:11-jre-slim
11-jre-slim: Pulling from library/openjdk
...
```

Note the image reference `library/openjdk`.

To make Jib load the image in your local Docker daemon, you should say `<image>docker://conf_server_image:latest</image>`. However, using an image from a Docker daemon incurs some overhead (which may be negligible). So, it may be better to push the base image to any container registry (a local private registry can work too) and have Jib use the image. Jib does cache base images, so using an image in a registry doesn't mean Jib will download it over and over. (But of course, if an image pointed to by a tag is updated, Jib will automatically download the updated image.)

There is another option where you can just get rid of the first `Dockerfile` step. Jib allows [adding any arbitrary files](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#adding-arbitrary-files-to-the-image) into the image through the [`<extraDirectories>`](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#extradirectories-object) feature. The default directory is `src/main/jib`, so for example, if you place `src/main/jib/foo/bar.txt`, your will have `/foo/bar.txt` in the built image. However, I understand that you may not want to put a personal `known_hosts` into the source repo. (Potentially, you could set up a special dev Maven profile that, for example, copies `known_hosts` into `src/main/jib` using the `copy-resources` goal from the Maven Resources plugin.)

You can also set some container configurations including ports in Jib.

```xml
<configuration>
  <container>
    ...
    <ports>
      <port>8888</port>
    </ports>
  </container>
</configuration>
```

Lastly, because you are using `jib:dockerBuild` which builds , I think `docker login` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to push your image to repository `registry-1.docker.io`

Change this section:

```
  <to>
     <image>${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</image>
  </to>
```

to:

```
<to>
  <image>yourDockerHubRepositoryName/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</image>
</to>
```